# Hibernate spring.jpa.mapping-resources=hibernate.cfg.xml not read after Spring-Boot 2.1.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

Spring-Boot 2.0.8 adds the mappings by creating entities from the *hbm.xml files listed in spring.jpa.mapping-resources=hibernate.cfg.xml, Any release after that ignores the mapping file.

```
javax.persistence.metamodel.Metamodel metaModel = emf.getMetamodel();
Set<EntityType<?>> entityTypeSet = metaModel.getEntities();
```

Anyone have an idea what i missed in either migration guides?

Comment: @Lemmy - How would you improve that question? It's an complete statement/Question. Nothing more can be said other than starting to list Hibernate code.

Comment: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-spring-jpa-mapping-resources-hibernate-cfg-xml-not-read-after-spring-boot-2-1-0/2207

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13250